Нужна ли запятая перед "насколько"?
Густо краснею, понимая (,) насколько ужасно себя веду. Или "насколько ужасно себя веду" является частью деепричастного оборота?

Правильно:
Густо краснЕю, // понимая, / насколько ужасно себя ведУ.
Пояснение
Запятая ставится.  Деепричастный оборот осложнен изъяснительным придаточным. Насколько — союзное слово в значении как.
Основная пауза делается после глагола, а перед придаточным пауза произносительная. Поэтому создается впечатление, что запятая не нужна. Но это грамматическая запятая.
